# Multiple jScrollPanes overlapping and preventing access to others

Tags: html, web, jscrollpane

I have a "1 page" website that has the content change via jQuery when you click on a link.

Here is a sample of the DIV layouts:

```
<div id="div1" class="scroll-pane">
</div>
<div id="div2" class="scroll-pane">
</div>
<div id="div3" class="scroll-pane">
</div>
```

So when you click on one link for example "div1" will fade out and "div2" (previously hidden) will fade in in its place. All of the DIVs have the same CSS positions as each other. My DIVs all have a jScrollPane, yet it seems they stack on top of each other and div3's pane is drawn on top of the others all of the time. I'm guessing that it has to do with the order they are created in the HTML maybe? 2's pane is above 1's pane, and 3's pane is above 2 and 1's pane.

So even when all of div3's contents are hidden its pane remains visible and overlapping the other two DIVs underneath. So I can only inderact with div3's scrollability while the other DIVs are 'underneath' and not reachable.

I can hide the JScrollPanes but I can only seem to handle all of them at the same time. If I tell jScrollPane to hide, they all hide... I've tried changing the zIndex of the DIVs rather than jScrollPane's classes as they fade in and out, but this doesn't change the zIndex of the panes themselves. As I have also hidden the DIVs but the panes remain behind.

Is there a way to control the jScrollPanes individually and make their zIndex change or make them actually hide individually along with their DIVs without just all of them disappearing?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have your javascript your using, or do you have more relevant html? If so can it be shared? So we can see whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only ever want to show one, and are using jquery.

Your correct in that it's to do with the html order div 3 is last so naturally if put in the same location as another div it will load in the same place above the other objects.

In jquery you can change the z-index property of a div or any html element by doing:

`$(#div1).css(z-index, 1);` // for divs

`$(.scroll-pane).css(z-index, 1);` // for classes

notice the difference between # and . for calling classes or id's.

Have a look at the following article about understanding z-indexing:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Your hiding all the JScrollPanes because when you do something like:

`$(.scroll-pane).hide();`

It will get all classes which have .scroll-pane assigned to themselves meaning it will get all three in your example.

The way to resolve this is to either have a unique class name like `.scroll-pane-1` `.scroll-pane-2` for each pane you want to individually hide and then have jquery that does:

`$(.scroll-pane-1).hide();`

`$(.scroll-pane-2).show();`

By doing so you can call hide function for each individual pane at different points like onclick, onload and it will affect the specific one dependent on when you call it.

In your case however you can just do:

```
<script>
var index = 0

$('#target').click(function() {

if(index == 0)
    {
        `$(#div1).hide();`
        `$(#div2).show();`
        `$(#div3).hide();`
         index = 1;

    }
if(index == 1)
    {
        `$(#div1).hide();`
        `$(#div2).hide();`
        `$(#div3).show();`
         index = 2;
    }
if(index == 2)
    {
        `$(#div1).show();`
        `$(#div2).hide();`
        `$(#div3).hide();`
         index = 0;
    }

});
</script>
```

It will produce the result since you already have unique div id's and we can call show and hide on them by using jqueries selector.

We created a integer variable which changes based on click so when link or button with id tag of target is clicked we check what value the integer is and based on its value we can show different results, the next time it's clicked the value will be different hence showing and hiding different objects.